# CFG for language

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I'm trying to create a cfg generating following language:

[image: foo+bar]

Is This language context-free and could be generated by a cfg? if yes , how could the grammar generating this language be created?

I'm not experienced so much in creating cfg's for cfl's. I would be glad if any help or solution is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you off, do you know how to create a CFG for the language `{a^n d^t | n = t}`? This will be your starting point.

```
S -> aSd | epsilon
```

From here, you need to extend what happens when there are more `a`s than `d`s, or more `d`s than `a`s. The goal will always be to make sure that for every `a` or `b` consumed on the left, a `c` or `d` is consumed on the right.

```
S -> aSd | aAc | bDd | epsilon
```

`A` is the case where there are more `a`s than `d`s, `D` is the other case. In each of these, you you need to consume a left character for every right character.

There's an additional case, which is the case that either or both of `n` and `t` are `0`. I'll leave it to you to determine how to handle that.

Then you'll have to deal with running out of one side's character. For example, if you're in state `A`, you expect to match `a`s with `c`s until the `a`s run out and turn into `b`s. Something like,

```
A -> aAc | bCc
```

I'll leave the rest to you to figure out.